# Changing a property in provider executes all Consumers

Tags: flutter, dart

I have CounterProvider mixin with ChangeNotifier and inside the class i have two counters (_counterOne and _counterTwo) when _counterOne is inremented all Consumers are executed hence Widgets that consume _counterOne and _counterTwo are executed. But I want only the _counterOne consumer widget to execute.
I couldn't found any salution to do that.
Thanks in advance.

**Provider:**

```
class CounterProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  int _counterOne = 1;
  int getCounterOne() => _counterOne;
  void incrementCounterOne() {
    _counterOne++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int _counterTwo = 2;
  int getCounterTwo() => _counterTwo;
  void incrementCounterTwo() {
    _counterTwo++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**View:**

```
class CounterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CounterPage({super.key});
  @override
  State<CounterPage> createState() => _CounterPageState();
}

class _CounterPageState extends State<CounterPage> {
  late CounterProvider _provider;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _provider = Provider.of<CounterProvider>(context, listen: false);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
          body: Column(
        children: [
          Consumer<CounterProvider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
            print("Consumer of CounterOne executed");

            return Text("CounterOne: ${value.getCounterOne()}");
          }),
          Consumer<CounterProvider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
            print("Consumer of CounterTwo executed");

            return Text("CounterTwo: ${value.getCounterTwo()}");
          }),

          // Buttons
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _provider.incrementCounterOne();
            },
            child: const Text("Increment CounterOne"),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _provider.incrementCounterTwo();
            },
            child: const Text("Increment CounterTwo"),
          ),
        ],
      ));
}
```

Comment: You need two separate `ChangeNotifier`s to achieve that and add both with `MultiProvider`. Or you can use a `ValueListenableBuilder` if it fits your requirements.

Comment: if you need more complexity, to listen only to some parameters I recommend you to look at riverpod https://riverpod.dev/. For example you can do a .select(myClass.value) and listen only to the changes on this value in your consumer

Comment: ValueListenableBuilder solved the problem, I will look into riverpod documentation. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

according to how Provider works if you use Consumer on a Provider class it will listen to any changes on that class and update every time there is change, To solve this you can use `Selector` as explained in [here](https://samderlust.com/dev-blog/flutter-dart/flutter-the-use-of-selector-in-provider-package#:%7E:text=Selector%20is%20a%20class%20in,method%20of%20Selector%20will%20rebuild.).

But `ValueListenableBuilder` also works fine as suggested in the comments.